# Rustで#[wasm_bindgen]アトリビュートを付与するかどうか、ターゲットファミリーで制御したいです

Tags: rust, webassembly

Rustでdomain(entity)ロジックをcliとwasmのコードで共有したいです。
しかし、wasmの関数には`#[wasm_bindgen]`を付与しないといけないため、以下のようにターゲットがwasmかどうかで生成する関数を制御しています。

domain.rsから抜粋

```
#[cfg(target_family = "wasm")]
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32{
    a + b
}

#[cfg(not(target_family = "wasm"))]
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32{
    a + b
}
```

https://github.com/iranika/chimey

本当なら関数を一元化するために`#[wasm_bindgen]`を付与するかどうかを制御したいですが、`#[cfg(target_family = "wasm")]`ではアトリビュート単体の制御は出来ないはずです。
(もしできる方法があったら教えていただきたいです)

なにかいい方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

`#[cfg_attr(a, b)]`が使えそうです。

#[cfg(a)]が有効だったら#[b]をするという動作をするので、質問のケースに合致すると思います。

```
#[cfg_attr(target_family = "wasm", wasm_bindgen)]
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
```

資料（英語ですが...）

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute